# WickedPDF - Couldn't find user without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wicked-pdf

I have WickedPDF working in my application and am trying to add the PDF as an attachment. I have seen the following SO question [Rails 3 -Render PDF from view and attach to email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762583/rails-3-render-pdf-from-view-and-attach-to-email/5813394#5813394) and was following the answer from Unixmonkey. I have the following set up:

**Controller**

```
 def overtime
    @hospital_bookings = HospitalBooking.scoped
    hospital_booking = @hospital_bookings
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
```

I believe the above should work according to the SO question. However I am getting `ActiveRecrod::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find User without an ID`.

**Updates**

**routes**

```
`get "overtime" => "hospital_bookings#overtime", :as => "overtime" `
```

Comment: Could be the URL you're using doesn't match the route definition, can you post your routes for this method?

Comment: are you trying to grab the current user information? If so do `@user = current _user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the following line in your controller:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

You don't appear to be passing an `id` parameter in your route. Depending on your authentication model, you'll need to use `current_user` or pass an `id` to your route.

Comment: Yes I get that.. >_< I am using CanCan. Like Matt suggested I should be doing @user = current_user. Thank you as well Robin. Should really be Matts answer. If you could upvote him too.