# Error in attempt to create a PDF with wkhtmltopdf (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, paperclip, wkhtmltopdf

Every time that I try to "Create a contract" in my system, Sidekiq show me this error :

> Failed to execute:
>   ["/fullpath/operations/app/views/contract_mailer/contract_email.html.erb",
>   "/var/folders/0g/zqwyw_w11tld3w98vx9qf_vc0000gp/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20170330-28967-pvuw5y.pdf"]
>   Error: PDF could not be generated! Command Error: Error: Failed
>   loading page
>   file:////fullpath/operations/app/views/contract_mailer/contract_email.html.erb
>   (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with
>   --load-error-handling ignore) Exit with code 1, due to unknown error.

I'm not understanding why this is happening, I followed every single step of the documentation and etc. My HTML file is OK too (apparently). 
Specifications of my system and some gems that I'm using:

- Ruby 2.3.3 
    Rails 4.1.8 
    gem 'sidekiq', '~> 4.0.0'  gem
  'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin' 
    gem
  'sidekiq-cron', '~> 0.4.0' 
    gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2' 
    gem
  'paperclip', '~> 4.3.7' 
    gem 'wicked_pdf' 
    gem
  'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge', '~> 0.12.2.1'

Comment: Do you have `contract_email.pdf.erb`

Comment: Inside my "views"? Nope

Comment: You might want to add the same action file like `.html.erb` as `.pdf.erb`

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30136955/4758119

Comment: OK, let me try this here

Comment: It's obligatory have that wicked_pdf tags in my HTML file?

Comment: You will need to create `.pdf.erb` and you need to change styleshhet and javascript tag to use `wickedpdf_tag`

Comment: normal `stylesheet_tag`, `javascript_tag` and `image_tag` won't work

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question, but what that `<%= yield %>` do?

Comment: It will render the content of the `action`  in that case content inside `app/views/pdf/pdf_view.pdf.erb`